# How can I display an attribute from each post inside foreach($latest_posts1 as $post )

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I want to display an block attribute named "paragraph" that exists in each post inside a CPT named "test".
I have no issues displaying the current page attributes(selectLgColumns & borderClass). The problem is I am not able to get the block attributes from the post that are indise the CPT. I don't know much php. I used the documentation to come up with the following code. Can anyone please help?

```php
<?php
 
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'register_latest_post');
function register_latest_post() {
    register_block_type('boot/block-lead1', [ 'render_callback' => 'render_latest_post1'
    ]);
}
    
function render_latest_post1( $attributes ) {
    $column = $attributes['selectLgColumns'];
    $border = $attributes['borderClass'];
    $desc = $attributes['desc'];
    
    $latest_posts1 = wp_get_recent_posts( [
        'post_type' => 'test',
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'attributes' => 'attributes' //not sure how to get the attributes from each post.
        ] );
    if(empty($latest_posts1)){
        return '<p>No posts</p>';
    }
    $posts_output = '<div class="latest-postss">'; 
    foreach($latest_posts1 as $post ) {
    
    $post_id = $post['ID'];
    function render_latest_post( $attributes ) { //not sure how to use this function
    $para = $attributes['paragraph']; // I need to display this attribute from the block Thats added in the post
    }
    $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' );

    $posts_output .= '<div class="post-title ' .$column. ' ' .$border. '">
                            <img src="'. $post_thumbnail .'" class="img-fluid" loading="lazy" />
                            <h2>
                                <a href="'.get_permalink($post_id). '">
                                    '.get_the_title( $post_id ).'
                                </a>
                            </h2>
                             <p> ' .$column. ' ' .$border. ' </p>
                            <p>Desc: ' . $para . ' </p>
                            
                            
                      </div>';
    }
    $posts_output .= '</div>';
 
    return $posts_output;
    
}
 
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_rest_images1' );
function register_rest_images1(){
        register_rest_field( array('test'),
            'fimg_url',
            array(
            'get_callback' => 'get_rest_featured_image1',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema' => null,
            )
        );
}

function get_rest_featured_image1( $object, $field_name, $request) { if( $object['featured_media'] ) {
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $object['featured_media'], 'app-thumb' ); return $img[0];
    }
    return false;
}
 
function parse_blocks1( $content ) {
    
    $parser_class = apply_filters( 'block_parser_class', 'WP_Block_Parser' );
 
    $parser = new $parser_class();
    return $parser->parse( $content );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by block attribute. If you’re talking about regular WordPress/Gutenberg blocks then wanting an attribute form a single paragraph is a very unusual request. What attribute d o you want? And why only from a single paragraph?

Comment: Hey Jacob... Yes, It is a wordpress gutenberg block but its a custom block with TextareaControl. This block goes in each custom post type named test. I want to display this attribute on a page just like the title and featured image where all post are displayed. Basically I want to create a testimonial block which pulls data from a cpt post.

Comment: if the data is intended for the post, why store it on a block and not on the post as post meta or a term? It's not possible to query posts by the attributes on their blocks, any more than it's possible to query for posts by the attributes on HTML tags in their post content, it's not something you're supposed to do or need. Also please fix the indenting in your code, it's very difficult to read without proper indentation, and leads to beginner level mistakes that are hidden, e.g. you're declaring a named function in the middle of a for loop

Comment: I've edited the code to try and fix some of the formatting so it's clearer when functions start and begin but you'll need to fix the rest of the indenting yourself. Remember that blocks are just content, you aren't supposed to query by them. If you need to store information at a posts level you should store it in terms or post meta, the same way categories/tags or other data are stored. Blocks are just content, the same way shortcodes and paragraphs etc are just content, they get saves as HTML in the database

Comment: Tom, I have already specified I dont know php. I dont know how to format it.

Comment: Jacob, I created static block to display testimonials. Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Z9NJuNJ I am using bootstrap to display these testimonials in 3 columns using bootstrap classes. The idea is to create dynamic blocks where each testimonial will be a post from a CPT named testimonial. If I create meta fields or ACF fields, I wont be able to control the UI of the testimonial. The custom fields or ACF field needs to be configured in template. Hence I want to use Block parameters to display the block in each post as well as the page where it loads all testimonials.

Comment: I think you are lost in terminology: These `$attributes` are not the post's attributes, but the block's attributes. A post consists of one or more blocks, and each block may or may not have attributes. Also please move the function `render_last_post` outside, because in PHP (unlike JavaScript), every function is in its outer scope anyway.

Comment: @rexkogitans I started working with wordpress and php  a little year ago. I am still learning it each day. Gutenberg Blocks is the thing that got me interested in it. Yes, I meant block attributes and not post attributes. If we can retrive title, featured image etc then we should be able to retrive block attributes as well in the loop. I am not sure if its possible. If this is possible, then Gutenberg Blocks will be really awesome ... a lot of things can be done if this works, obviously it will be independent of whichever theme you use. Gutenberg is a brilliant idea for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this https://wholesomecode.ltd/using-post-meta-fields-to-store-attributes-in-the-wordpress-block-editor-gutenberg . This seems a better option. I updated the block attributes with meta & source. I was able to register the attribute as meta and retrive it using php. This way I do not have to depend on meta fields or ACF. Its theme independant too. It doesnt matter how many blocks are added on the page. All it needs is a particular block thats mandatory to add the concerning data for eg: heading, custom-website-link- etc.

Block Preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2bQ0.jpg
Those three testimonials come from a CPT testimonials. The block that lists the testimonial post has the option to

1. Select column size
2. BG color classes and more

I love Gutenberg. Yayyyy!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is the post's content which has blocks, and these blocks have attributes. Internally, these are stored as some fancy HTML comments. To get the rendered HTML, you can use the function [get_the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) and pass it through the filter [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/). I.e., replace

```
function render_latest_post( $attributes ) { //not sure how to use this function
    $para = $attributes['paragraph']; // I need to display this attribute from the block Thats added in the post
    }
```

with

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content(null, false, $post['ID']));  // not really, I will explain below
```

Beware that you will retrieve the entire rendered HTML, I am not sure how you want to get a single paragraph from it. Either you go another way where it is enough to have the entire post, or you play around with the PHP classes `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` having a lot of fun with a gazillions of edge cases.

One more thing: **For performance reasons, do not pass around the post ID all the time!** Instead, fetch the post once:

```
$postobj = get_post($post['ID']);
```

and then pass around this object to all functions like `get_the_post_thumbnail`, `get_the_title`, `get_the_content` because they make a database access if an ID is passed, but do not if a `WP_Post` object is passed.

So, you should end up with

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content(null, false, $postobj));
```